# Insert new article in joomla 3 via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, joomla3.3

I want to create new content in Joomla by running a query via phpmyadmin.

I checked the MySQL query log when I create a new article, and there are multiple insert queries (table content, assets, ucm_content...)

So can you help me, how to insert a completely new article to database via phpmyadmin. Or is there a simple code to do this?

Comment: Can you please show your current query?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an article to Joomla, all you need to do is to add that article to the `content` table. Do not worry about the `assets` table or other tables.